# Continuous compounding in practice

Tags: calculation, interest, compound-interest

A common explanation for the [mathematical constant *e*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28constant%29) (2.71828...) is that it is the factor by which an investment would grow at 100% interest rate over a period if it is *continuously compounded*.

In other words, if you were to invest 1 million dollars for one year at a rate of 100%, after one year, the balance would show about 2.71 M$ (or ***e*** M$)

However, it is not a case I have ever seen. We often see monthly compounding, sometimes daily, but I've never seen *continuous compounding*.

Does continuous compounding exist in practice? Is it ever part of a financial product offering? If so, in which cases might it be used?

Comment: I think the point is for you to adjust the variables in that formula to a real world scenario.

Answer (score 9):

Continuous compounding at an interest rate of 100% is unlikely to be used in practice. More generally, if the interest rate is x% per annum and interest is compounded n times during the year (so that at the end of each sub-interval,
the amount increases by a factor of (1 + (x/100)/n) ), then the amount has
increased over the year by a *factor* of

> (1 + (x/100)/n)^n which is approximately e^(x/100) = 1 + (x/100) + (x/100)^2/2 + (x/100)^3/6 + .... when n is large.

Mathematically, e^(x/100) is the limiting value of (1+(x/100)/n)^n as n 
tends to infinity.
Heuristically, (1 + (x/100)/n)^n gets closer and closer to e^(x/100)
as n gets larger and 
larger (from quarterly to monthly to daily to hourly .... compounding).

So, let us turn the problem around.  If the *annual percentage
yield* (not the same as the APR) is specified as y% per annum,
then let x be the solution to the equation

> e^(x/100) - 1 = (y/100)

which gives x = 100 log_e (1 + y/100)% as the rate that would be quoted
as the APR for continuous compounding while the APR for monthly
compounding would be quoted as the solution to

> (1 + (x/100)/12)^12 = 1 + y/100

which gives x = 12 times 100 times the 12th root of (1 + y/100) % as the APR.

As a comparison, an annual percentage yield of 5% per annum corresponds to a 
quoted rate (APR) of 4.88894...% per annum compounded monthly and 4.8790...% per
annum compounded continuously.  Weekly and daily compounding would
result in quotes somewhere in between these two figures, but as 
you can see, for a given annual percentage yield, continuous compounding 
really does 
not make that the APR significantly smaller than the more
common monthly compounding used for mortgages, auto loans, and
the like.

Comment: +1 what a beautiful explanation, an upvote and hat tip, Dilip.

Comment: If you want 5% gain over the year and want to compound using n intervals you will get 105% at the year end by using `initial*(interestPerPeriod + 1)^n` where `interestPerPeriod = (x + 1)^(1/n) - 1` and `x = 0.05`. That's the maths at least. The APR method appears to be something different. If I didn't get 105% I'd be worried.

Comment: @ChrisDegnen You are working things backwards. Normally, interest rates are quoted as x% per annum compounded z-ly where z could be "annual, quarter, month, week, dai, hour" etc. in which case at the end of the n periods comprising a year, you will get (1+x/100n)^n = 1+y/100 and the APR is y%. You are starting with an APR of y% and asking, if the interest is computed n times in the year, what is the interest-per-period (IPP)? When you solve for IPP, you can get the "quoted rate" as (n times IPP %) compounded n-ly). The APR is required by law to be stated on all loans, but what is used is IPP.

Comment: The cause of this misunderstanding is that in the [European Union, APR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annual_percentage_rate#European_Union) (annual percentage rate) is the effective annual rate, or annual percentage yield as you put it (5%).  The APR you quote (4.879%) is the nominal rate, or [logarithmic rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_return#Logarithmic_or_continuously_compounded_return), which is not quoted in the EU.  In the EU monthly rates are calculated as `(APR/100 + 1)^(1/12) - 1`, which in this example would be 0.4074%. Or from log return, `e^(0.04879*1/12) - 1 = 0.4074%`.

Comment: @ChrisDegnen Yes, APR seem to mean different things in the US and the EU.  The 5% annual percentage yield (APY) of the US can, as I said, be stated as an APR of 4.88894...% per annum compounded monthly, making the per-month rate to be 4.88894/12 = 0.4074116..%. which is exactly what you get from the EU APR of 5% via (1+APR)^{1/12}-1.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some calculations for an investment which yields a final value of $ e million ($2,718,282) from an initial value of $ 1 m.

The [logarithmic or continuously compounded return](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_return#Logarithmic_or_continuously_compounded_return) is given as:-

[image]

```
Vf = 2,718,282
Vi = 1,000,000
rlog = ln(Vf/Vi) = 1.0 = 100 %
```

This is a logarithmic return, or *nominal return (continuously compounded)* of 100%.

The [effective annual rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_interest_rate#Calculation) can be calculated by:-

[image]

where `i` is the logarithmic or continuously compounded nominal rate.

```
i = rlog = 1.0 = 100%
r = e^i - 1 = 1.718282 = 171.8282 %
```

An effective annual return of 171.8282% produces the final value of $ e million.

Of course, the effective return can also be calculated as:

```
r = Vf/Vi - 1 = 1.718282 = 171.8282 %
```

***Now considering monthly periodic returns***

The [effective annual rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_interest_rate#Calculation) calculated from a periodically compounded nominal return is:

[image]

where `n` is the number of compounding periods.

Rearranging this formula, and using the previously calculated effective annual rate (which produced $ e million), the annual *nominal rate compounded monthly* is calculated:

```
r = 1.718282 = 171.8282 %
n = 12
i = n*((r + 1)^(1/n) - 1) = 1.0428486 = 104.28486 %
```

Note how this differs from the 100% calculated for the continuously compounded nominal rate.  As `n` increases the periodic nominal rate approaches the continuously compounded nominal rate, as demonstrated by the [limit formula](http://www.math.cornell.edu/twiki/bin/view/MSC/UsefulLimits):

[image]

For example, the nominal rate compounded daily (with `n = 365`) is 100.137%, which is somewhat closer to 100% than the nominal rate compounded monthly.

From the annual nominal rate compounded monthly, the monthly compounding rate can be found:

```
m = i/n = 1.0428486/12 = 0.08690405 = 8.690405 %
```

Checking by compounding for 12 months: `(m + 1)^n - 1 = 1.718282`

The monthly compounding rate can also be calculated directly from the logarithmic rate, or annual continuously compounded nominal rate:

```
i = rlog = 1.0 = 100 %
n = 12
m = e^(i/n) - 1 = 8.690405 %
```