# APR without principal repayment?

Tags: mortgage, loans, interest, apr

I've been trying to find out about this own my own but can't seem to work it out via search engines, loan/mortgage websites and excel.

When I try to work out how much a loan costs, rates like APR seem to ask for monthly payment or no. of payments. AND when they work out or use "payment", they include both the capital repayment and the interest (+fees).

Is there a term that describes Percentage rate that constitutes interest and fees of the loan but not the loan amount itself **EDIT: more like "principal amount"**? i.e. a percentage of your "out of pocket" expense not including the money you borrowed which i think better reflects the cost of a loan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4 years and 7 months later, looking back at the question, the term i think I was looking for is "Cost of Loan"

Answer (score 2):

With most loans in the US, you get what is called an 
amortization schedule which shows how
each (monthly) payment gets divided into capital repayment and interest+fees.
The monthly payment is fixed; it is the same amount month after month.
*But,* the breakdown of the payment into capital repayment and interest
payment differs from month to month as earlier payments are mostly interest
and later payments are mostly capital repayment. This is because each
month the money still owing goes down and so the interest for *next*
month is less.  With a fixed monthly payment, *next* month's interest is
a little less and capital repayment is a little more.  In this scenario,
if the **total** of the many monthly payments is $X and you borrowed $Y
to start with, then your **total cost** of borrowing money is simply $(X-Y).
What interest rate did you pay for borrowing the money? It is the APR divided
by 12 **per month.**  That is, if you borrowed $1000 at 6%APR compounded
monthly, then you owe $1000x0.5% = $5 in interest at the end of the
first month. If the loan is for 5 years (60 equal monthly payments), you
pay $19.33 each month. In the first month, you have paid $5 in interest
and reduced the principal due by $14.33 (that is, you owe
only $985.67). So *next* month you owe only $4.93 = $985.67x0.5%
in interest, but since the monthly payment is still fixed at $19.33, you
get to pay off $14.40 (a tad more than last month's $14.33) of the
amount still outstanding.  Lather, rinse and repeat until your
60th payment of $19.33 consists of $19.23 of principal finally being
paid off together with 10 cents interest for that last month on that
$19.23 you still owed.  You will have paid $19.33x60 = $1159.80
in monthly payments, that is, $159.80 in interest over the life of
the loan. If you want to think of it as 15.98% interest over 5 years
or a shade under 3.2% per year, feel free to do so. However, most people
won't think of it that way, because they didn't have the use of the
full $1000 for the entire 60 month period.  Note that **there is no
compounding of interest,** that is, **you are not charged interest
on previously accrued interest** because you are paying off the interest
in full each month.

It is also possible to get interest-only loans where each month you
only pay the interest (and the fees) accrued that month. At the end,
the entire loan amount is due (usually called a balloon payment).
Note that the monthly payment is fixed in this instance too.  Thus,
you pay $5 interest each month and at the end of the loan period,
you owe the full $1000 since you have not repaid any part of it.
In fact, your *last* payment would be $1005 consisting of the
interest for that last month plus the full principal amount.  Note that
there is **no compounding of interest,** that is, **you are not
charged interest on previously accrued interest** *even though there is*
**no repayment of any part of the principal over the entire life of
the loan.**

Hybrids of these two types of arrangement such as "pay the interest and fees
each month plus $20 towards the principal" are also possible. This
would pay off our example loan of $1000 in 50 months instead of 60.
Note that each month's payment would be smaller
than the previous month's payment because the amount of interest 
charged each month is decreasing by $20x0.5% = 10 cents each month.

But note that in all these cases, the *percentage* interest you pay
each month is still the same APR/12.  What differs in the three
cases is *what the interest is being charged on.*  And it is all
**simple** interest, not compound interest, that is charged. The
phrase "6% APR compounded monthly" merely means that you pay 0.5%
per month simple interest on the remaining balance. If it said
"compounded quarterly" and you were making quarterly instead if
monthly payments, you would pay 1.5% per quarter, and it would
still be simple interest each quarter on the remaining balance.

In a different scenario, if **you** lend money to a bank (this is 
usually called a Certificate of Deposit or CD) for 5 years at 6% APR 
compounded quarterly (that's what *my* bank offers instead of monthly
compounding -- your bank might be different), then the interest 
*is* compounded and at the end of 5 years (20 quarters) when the
CD matures, you will get

> $1000 x (1 + 0.015)^20 = $1346.86

The **compounding** has increased the interest that you
have earned from 6% x 5 = 30% to 34.686%
which is 6.136% compounded annually or, if *you* like to think about
it differently, you got 34.686%/5 = 6.937% simple interest per annum.
(Most everyone else will beg to differ, but whatever makes you comfortable).
This is how CDs work in
the US. In India, CDs are commonly called FDs (Fixed Deposits)
and the interest accrued is paid out quarterly (or monthly
depending on the way it is set up) to the owner;
that is, interest does not accumulate *inside* the CD as it does
in the US (hence *Fixed* Deposit), and it is all *simple* interest:
no compounding since it is all paid out. You would get 1.5% per quarter
($15) for a total of $300 instead of the $346.86 that compounding
would give you (but only after 5 years). But, getting back to the
US, interest earned inside a CD must be declared annually as income
and the bank will include it in the 1099-INT that it sends you
(and the IRS), and you have to pay tax on that money from other
assets or income since you won't have that cash in hand till the
CD matures.

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate answer. I am definitely talking first scenario. Is the amortization calculable and fixed or are the lenders free to fiddle with the schedule as they see fit (before actually lending)?

Comment: I think what I missed was the fact that the interest rate is **compounded** and to work out new principal on which to be charged interest next, principal repayment is obviously needed. please conclude your answer with this so that people will know how it actually answered my question and i'll accept your answer

Comment: Amortization schedules _should_ be the same in all cases; and calculators are available widely on the Internet.  However, sometimes games are played with fees etc. For example, mortgage payments are usually due on the first of the month. If the closing is in the middle of April, the first payment is due on June 1 (for interest accrued May 1 - May 31), and you have the option of _pre-paying_ interest for the remainder of April, or have that April interest tacked on to the principal amount (lender will suggest this).

Comment: I have no idea what is meant by interest being compounded. You pay simple interest on the amount still owed, and since you pay off the interest each month, there is no _compounding_ of interest, that is, no interest is charged on the interest. See also [this question](http://money.stackexchange.com/q/18573/5760).

Comment: ok, not exactly _compounded_ but **recalculated** every month.